# Does changing the language on a kindle change the books?

Tags: kindle, language

If I change my Kindle’s language setting from English(us) to English(UK) will that change the language used in the Ebooks? Will Color be displayed as Colour in a Ebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it only affects system language, hour format etc.
Your books won't be changed :)